# Equality test for numeric value input parameter received as String data type

Tags: java

I am receiving a numeric value input parameter that is a String data type (something that I cannot change) and I need to check that this value received is of a certain number. I.e. Check if the value is 5.

Knowing that the received value of String data type, but at all times it will should contain only numbers. I would first convert the value into an integer data type, and then perform the equality test. I.e. Case B illustrated below.

Case A:

```
String expected = "3"; 

if(expected.equals(actual)) //...
```

Case B:

```
int expected = 3;

int actualInt = Integer.parseInt(actual);

if(expected == actualInt) //...
```

I would like to find out if there will be any cons in performing the equality test using Case B as I am more inclined to do it that way as a correct way out.

Comment: Only cons can be a need for `exception handling` for `NumberFormatException`. But since you are saying that your string only contains `number`, so its perfectly fine.

Comment: It would depend on how many comparison you will have to do inside your method. If you're doing few comparisons (let's say, 5 or 10) and the `String` parameter is short (length no more than 3 or 4) then you can use the A method, otherwise you should use the B method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only going to do equality check then I think case A is fine, since you are not doing any operations that will require you the number instead of a string.

Only cons I could see with case B, is that you would have to parse the number out of the string for the equality check.

But the advantage of case B is that if you needed to make sure that the string is actually an integer, in which case, you would have to go with case B.

Answer (score 4):

Use Try-Catch:

```
int expected = 3;
int actualInt;
try
{
    actualInt = Integer.parseInt(actual);

    if(expected == actualInt) //...
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    // You will reach here when a bad input is given to the parseInt method
    // Handle the failure
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // All other exceptions here
}
```

Even though you know that the string is always going to have a "numeric" value, it is still a good practice to implement exception handling. Better safe than worry :)

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using the overloaded versions of the static factory method valueOf() in String class.

String caters these methods to implicitly convert objects to its corresponding string representation.

Here is an example.

```
int expected = 3;
String.valueOf(expected).equalsIgnoreCase(actual); // is the equality check for numbers.
```

Assuming 'actual' is the parameter being passed. You might like to do a null check on the variable 'actual'.